# .htaccess forctype not working on godaddy anymore possible rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My website will no longer execute an extensionless url as php anymore. I had the following in my .htaccess file which was working fine until today.

```
<Files pages> 
  ForceType x-httpd-php5-cgi 
</Files>
```

This causes http://www.mydomain.com/pages/1/Home to run as pages/ as though it was pages.php.

Godaddy is not giving much support at this time other than indicating that they have or are updating from Apache 2.2 to 2.4.

Is it possible to do what i was doing with a rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your .htaccess file:

```
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php
```

This should allow the ForceType to work properly!
F.Y.I: I had the exact same issue, so I called GoDaddy tech support, and surprisingly they were able to solve the problem. It did in fact have to do with the switch to Apache 2.4 and some changes in GoDaddy's servers.
Good Luck!

Edit:
I forgot to mention that a php5.ini file that sets cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1 is necessary!
If you are getting a "No input file specified" error, this should solve it.

Comment: Where do i add these lines? and do i leave what i had between <Files pages></Files>?

Comment: without changing anything i added the lines (to the top of the .htaccess file and i now get No Input File Specified.?  I may not be putting your lines in the right spot?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you - you can add `AddHandler` and `Options +ExecCGI` between <files> if you only want it to work within `files`. And yes, the php5.ini was also necessary!